# Game freezes when first playing animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit to make a game and when I play animation first time the game stops for few frames, and this is very annoying. How can I fix that?
When I load my SKSpriteNode I load animation textures like this:

```
    self.frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    SKTextureAtlas *shieldAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"shield"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [shieldAtlas.textureNames count]; i++) {
        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"shield%.3d", i];
        SKTexture *tempTexture = [shieldAtlas textureNamed:tempName];
        if (tempTexture) {
            [self.frames addObject:tempTexture];
        }}
```

When it's time to play it I make action as usual and it freezes right here. After the first time everything works just fine without any slowdown.

```
[self.shield runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.frames timePerFrame:0.1 resize:YES restore:NO]] withKey:@"shield"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this block of code right after adding texture to array helped me. I guess they are lazy loaded and only loaded to memory when accessed.

```
[tempTexture preloadWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // duh duh
}];
```